# Batch - change account password with imput

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I want to create a batch file when launched asks the user to change the current administrator password.

```
Step 1: User logins
Step 2: Batch file runs displaying message "Please change Administrator password"
Step 3: user types in new password
Step 4: sets new password for Administrator account
Step 5: deletes batch file
```

Step 5 must not happen unless the user changes password. I know how to set a task schedule for it to run just not sure what the code inside the .bat file needs to be.

Comment: Are you really wanting a 'User' to do this, or the 'Administrator'? Please also note, that we're not going to just write your code for you, for free. We expect that you've made some effort in achieving this goal yourself. Also this site expects a specific issue, not a series of them, so given that, which step are you requiring help with? Please read [ask], before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55539168/edit), to bring it on topic.

Comment: It is no good idea to prompt a user for a new password, especially the one for administrator account, in environment of Windows command prompt. The character set in a Windows command prompt environment is different to character set in GUI environment. So if the user enters any non ASCII character on password prompt for example with `set /P` during execution of the batch file, the user will not be able to enter the same password on prompt by Windows although the user presses the same keys on keyboard.

Comment: You might be better off using PowerShell. It already has cmdlets to get passwords without ever displaying them. See the examples near the bottom of the page at https://ss64.com/ps/set-adaccountpassword.html

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
Set "password123="

echo "Please change Administrator password"
set /P password123=Enter your new password: 
If Not Defined password123 goto :exit
net user administrator %password123%
del "%~f0"

:exit
exit
```

1. Echos "Please change Administrator password" as you requested
2. Prompts for a password to change admin pass.
3. Takes the user input and sets the pass.
4. If no pass is typed, the batch file exits
5. If a password is typed it deletes the bat file.

Comment: That's starting to look a little better, although using, `If Not Defined password123 Exit /B` or `If Not Defined password123 GoTo :EOF` and deleting the three unnecessary lines at the bottom would still be better. As for the self delete line, I recommended, `(GoTo) 2>Nul & Del "%~f0"`, because yours should, for the fraction of a second before it closes, output a `cannot be found` message.